# com.google.android.gcm.server.InvalidRequestException: HTTP Status Code: 401 while sending GCM message

Tags: java, google-cloud-messaging

I have been trying to send GCM message to the android device from my server API. But getting 401 invalidrequestexception. Code used is:

```
public static Map<String, Object> prepareGCMMessage(String loginUserName, String loginUserPhone,                                                       String destinationPhone){

    Map<String, Object> messageMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    String message= generateInviteMessage(loginUserName,loginUserPhone);

    messageMap.put(ApplicationConstants.TEXT_MESSAGE, message);
    messageMap.put(ApplicationConstants.SOURCE_NUMBER, loginUserPhone);
    messageMap.put(ApplicationConstants.TO_NUMBER, destinationPhone);

    return messageMap;
}

public static Boolean sendGCMNotification(Map<String, Object> messageMap, String contactDeviceId) {

    Sender sender = new Sender(ApplicationConstants.GCM_APP_KEY);

    Message.Builder messageBuilder = new Message.Builder();

    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> messageEntry : messageMap.entrySet()) {
        messageBuilder.addData(messageEntry.getKey(), String.valueOf(messageEntry.getValue()));
    }

    Message notificationMessage = messageBuilder.build(); //add timeToLive here

    try {
        Result result = sender.send(notificationMessage, contactDeviceId, 3);

        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(result.getErrorCodeName())) {
            LOGGER.info( "GCM Notification is sent successfully to android for device Id: {0}", contactDeviceId);
            return true;
        }
        LOGGER.info( "Error occurred while sending push notification: {0}", result.getErrorCodeName());

    }
    catch (InvalidRequestException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Invalid Request: {0}", e);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("IO Exception: {0}", e);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: 401 response means request is unauthorized.

Comment: yes buddy..but the app key is correct here..what is wrong in the request here?

Comment: Post your `Sender` code, if using `HttpURLConnection`, you need to call `urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "key=" + API_KEY);`

Comment: Above code is the one sending the message. Sender class is from goggle api. imports are:                                                                                  import com.google.android.gcm.server.InvalidRequestException;
import com.google.android.gcm.server.Message;
import com.google.android.gcm.server.Result;
import com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender;

Comment: Does the response body have anything?

Comment: Can you run this curl command and tell us its output? `curl --header "Authorization: key=<your API key>" \
       --header Content-Type:"application/json" \
       https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send \
       -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"ABC\"]}"`

Comment: Also make sure that your project in the Dev Console has the "Google Cloud Messaging for Android" API enabled.

Comment: you can refer my answer posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35055871/3142342). Hope it helps :)

Comment: Most of the time the Authorization key we are using could be wrong.
Check http://dev.tapjoy.com/faq/how-to-find-sender-id-and-api-key-for-gcm/    to see you are using the correct key or not . I also got confused while selecting API key for firebase 
We have to use SENDER ID - API KEY pair in Cloud messaging tab under firebase setting.
i.e. 
Go to firebase App--> Go to app setting --> Cloud Messaging
there you can find Sender Id <==> API key 
and this API key you can use to send FCM.